# SELECT COM FORMATAÇÃO DE STRING

Tags: mysql, sql

Utilizando o Banco de Dados MySQL, tendo a intenção de realizar a consulta em uma determinada tabela cujo um de seus campos `data` possui como tipo `VARCHAR(8)`.

**Query SQL - Atual**

```
SELECT `t_movimentacao`.`data` FROM t_movimentacao 
WHERE `t_movimentacao`.`id` = '1';
```

Executando a query atual obtemos o seguinte retorno: `23072019`

```
|   data   |
- 23072019 -
```

Sabendo que a string contem uma data no formato dd/mm/yyyy, sem a caractere de `/` como podemos formatar e personalizar este campo diretamente na consulta do mesmo.

Desejo uma Query SQL - Formatando o campo data para obeter o segunte resultado na consulta: `23/07/2019`

```
|    data    |
- 23/07/2019 -
```

Como formatar a string para colocar as `/` e receber a data no formato desejado diretamente no SQL?

Answer (score 4):

Se não tiver a necessidade de trabalhar com DATA, somente para formatação e apresentação a partir do sql pode utilizar a função `CONCAT` e `SUBSTR`.
A função `CONCAT` concatena um ou mais parâmetros e a função SUBSTR extrai uma substring de uma string passando a string o inicio que deseja iniciar e quantos caracteres. Caso tenha necessidade, acredito que terá q converter a string em data e considerar a configuração do mysql.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(SUBSTR(t_movimentacao.data, 1, 2), "/", SUBSTR(t_movimentacao.data, 3, 2), "/", SUBSTR(t_movimentacao.data, 5, 4))
FROM t_movimentacao
WHERE t_movimentacao.id = '1';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente! Eu sabia que o SQL detêm funcionalidades avançadas de consulta embora não as conheça. Agradeço pelo espirito solicito de todos que aqui me ajudaram a resolver o problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT cast(left(data,2) as nvarchar) + '-' + SUBSTRING(data,3,2) + '-' + 
cast(RIGHT(data,4) as nvarchar) as data FROM t_movimentacao 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`t_movimentacao`.`data`, '%d / %m / %y') FROM t_movimentacao 
WHERE `t_movimentacao`.`id` = '1';
```

veja se vai assim

Comment: Infelizmente o valor retornou nulo.

Comment: Tenta alterar a letra maiuscula, ou algo pois o banco é Case Sensitive.

Comment: esse DATE_FORMAT funciona com uma data prevista já, o que pode ser feito é um outro select dentro retornando no primeiro select e utilizando após

Comment: Essa dica deve funcionar mesmo se o campo for vachar? infelizmente não estou logrando exito aqui.

Comment: Eu consigo obter algum resultado usando isso ```format(`t_movimentacao`.`11_data_de_movimentacao`, '%d/%m/%yyyy')``` e como resultado recebo a data nesse formato: `2,372,019`.

Comment: ATENÇÃO, não será útil utilizar a função DATE_FORMAT pois o campo não é do tipo DATE, é do tipo VARCHAR, ou seja, o DATE_FORMAT não irá entender como se o valor fosse data.